# Use loadtxt to read files recursively

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I have a large number of .asc files containing (x,y) coordinates for two given satellites. There are approximately 3,000 separate files for each satellite (e.g. Satellite1 = [file1,file2,..., file3000] and Satellite2= [file1,file2,..., file3000]).

I'm trying to write some code in Python (version 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.) that finds the multiple points on the Earth's surface where both satellite tracks crossover. 
I've written some basic code that takes two files as input(i.e. one from Sat1 and one from Sat2) using loadtxt. In a nutshell, the code looks like this:

```
sat1_in = loadtxt("sat1_file1.asc", usecols = (1,2), comments = "#") 
sat2_in = loadtxt("sat2_file1.asc", usecols = (1,2), comments = "#") 

def main():        
    xover_search() # Returns True or False whether a crossover is found.
    xover_final()  # Returns the (x,y) coordinates of the crossover.
    write_output() # Appends this coordinates to a txt file for later display.

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

I would like to implement this code to the whole dataset, using a function that outputs "sat1_in" and "sat2_in" for all possible combinations of files between satellite 1 and satellite 2. These are my ideas so far:

```
#Create two empty lists to store all the files to process for Sat1 and Sat2:
sat1_files = []
sat2_files = []

#Use os.walk to fill each list with the respective file paths:
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'sat1*.asc'):
        sat1_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'sat2*.asc'):
        sat2_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))  

#Calculate all possible combinations between both lists using itertools.product:
iter_file = list(itertools.product(sat1_files, sat2_files)) 

#Extract two lists of files for sat1 and sat2 to be compared each iteration:
sat1_ordered = [seq[0] for seq in iter_file] 
sat2_ordered = [seq[1] for seq in iter_file]
```

And this is where I get stuck. How to iterate through "sat1_ordered" and "sat2_ordered" using loadtxt to extract the lists of coordinates for every single file?The only thing I have tried is:

```
for file in sat1_ordered:
    sat1_in = np.loadtxt(file, usecols = (1,2),comments = "#")
```

But this will create a huge list containing all the measurements for satellite 1.

Could someone give me some ideas about how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are searching something like that:

```python
for file1, file2 in iter_file:
  sat1_in = np.loadtxt(file1, usecols = (1,2),comments = "#")
  sat2_in = np.loadtxt(file2, usecols = (1,2),comments = "#")
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Roman. From what I see, this generates two arrays containing (x,y) coordinates for sat_1 and sat_2 in the right order to be compared. But how to iterate through these two arrays to extract one file for each satellite at a time?

Comment: i.e.                                                            sat1_file1   sat2_file1 ----> use as input for main()           sat1_file1   sat2_file2 ----> use as input for main()               etc

Comment: Sry, but I can't understand you. Provide please more information. Do you want to iterate through sat1_in and sat2_in and if find crossover print it out to the output file?

Comment: The program I've written only takes one single file per satellite as input. The idea you've suggested returns two arrays containing all files for each satellite. I'm wondering if there is a way to iterate through "iter_file" to extract one file per satellite at a time, and feed this information into my program.

Comment: Here are some examples of my data:                            iter_file = list of files to compare               [('./c2p0001c054.asc', './j2p0001c218.asc'), ('./c2p0001c054.asc', './j2p0002c218.asc'), ('./c2p0001c054.asc', './j2p0003c218.asc'), ('./c2p0001c054.asc', './j2p0004c218.asc'), ('./c2p0001c054.asc', './j2p0005c218.asc'), ('./c2p0001c054.asc', './j2p0006c218.asc'),..........]                               sat1_in = array of latitudes and longitudes.                        [[ 69.075923  78.650553]
 [ 69.019283  78.630961]
 ..., 
 [-87.981672 -25.027398]
 [-87.983415 -26.63799 ]]

Comment: `The program I've written only takes one single file per satellite as input.` - What is format of this file?

Comment: I've added a different question with some mock up data to make it a bit clearer."iterate-through-a-list-of-numpy-arrays"